# how to solve:The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys

*Hi I have a WinForms .NET project which I delete some foreign keys and add another after that          when I try to update database the below error occured.would you please help me in this issue?*

````
 ```
  public PatientPayment()
    {
        delstatus = false;
    }
    //[Key, ForeignKey("visit")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool delstatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime regdate { get; set; }
    public Doctor doctor { get; set; }
    public Patient patient { get; set; }
    
    public Visit visit { get; set; }
    public string Payment { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }  
}
```
````

**and the other class**

````
     ```
   public class Visit
{
       public Visit()
    {
           delstatus = false;
          
        
        status = 0;
    }
    //[Key, ForeignKey("patientPayment")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool delstatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public Patient patient { get; set; }
    public Doctor doctor { get; set; }
    public PatientPayment patientPayment { get; set; }
```
````

**the error is:Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'ClinicBE.Visit' and 'ClinicBE.PatientPayment'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
I try to define foreign key here but does not solve the problem**